# Is there a reason that in a Voice Assistent Code the isp5 seems to be a Key Error?

Tags: python, virtual-machine, speech-recognition

I am a beginner at Python and want to write a simple voice Assistent. I wanted to Test the Code but a Error appeared.
The Code:

```
import subprocess

import wolframalpha

import pyttsx3

import tkinter

import json

import random

import operator

import speech_recognition as sr

import datetime

import wikipedia

import webbrowser

import os

import pyjokes

import feedparser

import smtplib

import ctypes

import time

import requests

import shutil

from twilio.rest import Client

from clint.textui import progress

from ecapture import ecapture as ec

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

#defining functions

def speak(audio) :

 engine.say(audio)

 engine.runAndWait()

 

def wishMe():

 hour = init(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

 if hour>= 0 and hour <12:

    speak('Good Morning Sir !')

 elif hour>= 12 and hour<18:

    speak('Good Afternoon Sir!')

 else:

    speak('Good Evening Sir!')

 assname = (' Beta Liar 1 point 0')

 speak('I am your assistent')

 speak(assname)

def username():

 speak('What should i call you master')

 uname = takeCommand()

 speak('Welcome Master')

 speak(uname)

 columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns

 

 print('###############'.center(columns))

 print('Welcome Master.', uname.center(columns))

 print('###############'.center(columns))

 

 speak('How can i Help you, Master')

 

def takeCommand():

  r = sr.Recognizer()

 

  with sr.Microphone() as source:

      print('Listening...')

      r.pause_threshold = 1

      audio = r.listen(source)

  try:

     print('Recognizing...')

     query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-in')

     print(f"User said: {query}\n")

  except Exception as e:

     print(e)

     print('Unable to Recognize your Voice.')

     return 'None'

  return query

 

# Main Function

if __name__ == 'main':

   clear = lambda: os.system('clear')

   

   

   clear()

   wishMe()

   username()
```

Now as you See it's a very beginner Code. Haha...
So heres the Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init

    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]

          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__

    o = self.data[key]()

        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^

KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/kali/Desktop/Python/liar.py", line 30, in <module>

    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init

    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)

          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__

    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)

                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__

    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)

                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module

    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/sapi5.py", line 1, in <module>

    import comtypes.client  # Importing comtypes.client will make the gen subpackage

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/comtypes/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>

    from _ctypes import COMError

ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

So the Key Error seems to be the sapi5. I think it's a Problem With the Module...

So I tryed to Reinstall pyttsx3 and the comtypes Module With pip. But it appeared the same Error... Maybe it's incompatible With Python3? I dont know anymore, maybe you can Help me. I use a Kali Linux VM With a Host on Windows

Comment: The `'sapi5'` option is only available on Windows.  I suggest you just remove that string and use the default.  And you can remove the `comtypes` module -- that's Windows-only.

Comment: Thank you,  yes I am a beginner and I Used a Tutorial for oriantation. That's why there ist Windows stuff in there.